# Dart editor: Tools/Generate JavaScript option disappeared

Tags: javascript, ide, dart, dart-editor

I just upgraded my Dart editor to the latest version and the option to generate JS has disappeared from the Tools menu. I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone else have this problem or any ideas what to do? Thanks!

Comment: I think I remember reading something about setting up dart2js as a transformer and using pub build instead.

Answer (score 2):

It has been removed and you should use Pub build instead:

> - Removed the Generate JavaScript menu option.
>
>   - Users should use pub build to generate javascript.

(From the [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+dartlang/posts/YfgcfhtDP6V) about the update).

Answer (score 1):

[Configuring the Built-in dart2js Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html)

In pubspec.yaml:

```
transformers:
    - $dart2js:
        checked: true
        minify: true
        verbose: true
        analyzeAll: true
        suppressWarnings: true
        suppressHints: true
        terse: true
```

Triggers on pub_build command performed (not pub get (my stumbling-block :-( )).